# Windows service not working after successful install and start (using Wix Toolset 3.7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, wix, wix3.7

I was looking for answers but not found one, so I'm posting this.

I have build a windows service, which I have to install on customer server. I have successfully tested it localy (installed with installutil.exe through Visual Studio cmd prompt). Now, I'm trying to do installation using Wix Toolset 3.7. The service installs and starts ok, but I don't get anything from it. It doesn't do anything, no calls to database (as it should) and nothing. It is there, it lives, but it doesn't do sqat. A bit lazy service it is.

I can not figure ot what am I doing wrong. Here is my Wix code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="NeoSrvKrka" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Neolab d.o.o." UpgradeCode="04f2a5be-92e1-4c53-8e45-7ae2740a9098">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="Neolab d.o.o." />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="NeoSrvKrka" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="NeoSrvKrka" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
             <Component Id="ProductComponent">
         <File Id="NeoSrvExe" Name="SalusWindowsService.exe" Source="..\SalusWindowsService\bin\Debug\SalusWindowsService.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes"></File>
         <File Id="NeoSrvExeConfig" Name="SalusWindowsService.exe.config" Source="..\SalusWindowsService\bin\Debug\SalusWindowsService.exe.config" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no"></File>
         <ServiceInstall
                    Id="ServiceInstaller"
                    Type="ownProcess"
                    Vital="yes"
                    Name="SalusKrkaService"
                    DisplayName="Salus Krka Service"
                    Description="Windows service za prenos narocil iz Salusa v Krko"
                    Start="auto"
                    Account="LocalSystem"
                    ErrorControl="ignore"
                    Interactive="no"
              >
         </ServiceInstall>
         <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="SalusKrkaService" Wait="yes" />
             </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

In my app I have also created ProjectInstaller file and all the magic around it (maybe I shoudln't use this with wix?). Oh, I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5, c#, windows 7 (will be windows server 2012 in production).

I am adding some code that should be executing:

```
namespace SalusWindowsService
```

{
    public partial class Krka : ServiceBase
    {
        public Krka()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000; //5 minut
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            timer.Enabled = true;

            GC.KeepAlive(timer);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //NeoException.Handle(exc);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { //do something, but it is not doing anything...}}}
```

I put some breakpoints in the code and even in the Main function of service (which just initializes base class), but I never get there.

Comment: Check the Windows eventviewer for errors like dbconnection fails, security fails, etc.

Comment: sorry, already done that, but there is nothing, no errors, no security fails or anything like that. I also attached process in debug mode, but nothing happens, as if the service never started, although I can see it in Service list and I can stop it, restart it and all that.

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing? Do you have a simple piece of code that you know of must be running?

Comment: I added some code which should be executing. But I don't think the problem is in code. The code itself is working just fine when I install it with installutil.exe. I looks like wix is not really installing anything or not installing correctly? I have also added reference of application to WIX setup project. I also have more dll's in application project. Should I add them to wix code like my exe and config file?

Comment: Remove the `try catch` please, or log the message to a file. Right now that causes nothing to show up in the event log. But removing it could also cause it to crash, so you still now something wrong happened there. On a side note: Try changing the user of the service to `Local System` so you can assume it is not security issue.

Comment: still no luck. I removed try/catch block as you suggested, but there is still nothing going on. I already had service set to LocalSystem, at least that is the parameter value in Product.wxs, like above in the code ServiceInstall > Account=LocalSystem). Or should I set that somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point about LocalSystem.  What is this timer supposed to be doing? Because for the sake of startup you could just write a single line to a file to check whether it is capable to do simple things. Make sure you write to a location that the local system has access to.

Comment: Hi Silvermind. I solved the problem, it was my mistake. I had to add additional dll-s to instalation package. I thought that all referenced dll-s in application combine in executable file of the applications. Obviously I was wrong, so the service could not perform it's operations since it has missing dlls. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, glad you have worked it out.

Comment: This question is answered in the question.  

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the  OP in the question. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> It turned out i wasn't adding enough dlls to installation.
>
> So, nothing wrong with Wix or the code. As a reminder for anyone out there doing the same mistake. You have to add ALL dll-s under wix . So, if you have multiple ddl-s in your Debug/bin folder of application, you have to add all (or at least many) of them into . That means, many tags inside one tag. Be careful, only one tag has KeyPath attribute set to "yes".